# Choosing the test statistic for this bootstrap

Tags: data-analysis, bootstrap-sampling

Say I have a (sample) bin with balls colored red, green, and blue.
I'm asked if the distribution of the colors is uniform with a required significance level of $0.01$, which means is there a $\dfrac{1}{3}$ chance to get each ball color if I take a ball randomly from the bin.

I want to use bootstrap sampling technique with confidence interval $99\%$. I stated the null hypotheses: the distribution of the colors is uniform.
And now I want to choose my test statistic. I'm finding it a little hard since there's three things to take care of: probability of red, blue, or green balls.
What I've thought of until now is choosing my test statistic as the total variation distance of the probabilities to get each ball in my bootstrapped samples, from the uniformly distributed sample.
I would love to hear any feedback about my thoughts and any ideas to make it better, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "bootstrapped" but you seem to saying you intend to look at $$\max\left(\left|\frac{n_{\text{red}}}{n}-\frac13\right|, \left|\frac{n_{\text{green}}}{n}-\frac13\right|, \left|\frac{n_{\text{blue}}}{n}-\frac13\right|\right)$$ as the test statistic from your sample, where the sample size is  $n=n_{\text{red}}+n_{\text{green}}+n_{\text{blue}}$.  That is not unreasonable, but you may have issues deciding what is the critical region. This distribution of this statistic would tend to be closer to $0$ for a larger sample size if the three probabilities are actually all equal to $\frac13$.

If instead you used $$\left(\frac{n_{\text{red}}}{n}-\frac13\right)^2+ \left(\frac{n_{\text{green}}}{n}-\frac13\right)^2+ \left(\frac{n_{\text{blue}}}{n}-\frac13\right)^2$$ then I think for reasonable $n$ you could multiply by $3n$ and then use a chi-squared distribution with two degrees of freedom (which turns out to be a scaled exponential distribution), perhaps using a continuity correction.

If $n$ is small, then you might prefer a [multinomial test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_test).

Comment: What I meant to use was: $\frac{\sum^k_{i=1}|p_i-\frac{1}{3}|}{2}$, which was the TVD formula that I learnt, the idea is to use bootstrap technique and calculate that for every sample and then see if the bounds contain $0$ in them, if yes I accept the null hypotheses otherwise I reject it.  I've seen it when we have like a null hypotheses: The mean of age of men is the same as the mean of age of women, there I can take the difference between them and use bootstrap, and if $0$ is in my interval I accept. So I'm wondering if it works in my case.

Comment: That seems a strange thing to do, but just accepting it as a toy example.  In your ages case you would not not take absolute values, so could concieve that your bootstrapping could have $0$ near enough to the middle of the distribution.  In your suggestion here with absolute values, it would at best be at one end of the bootstrap cases and at worst if the sample size is not a multiple of $3$ it would not be in the range of the possible outcomes of the bootstrapping.

Comment: I see, it's probably because I'm still in an introduction course, I thought it was a normal thing to do when bootstrapping, but let's say I used the statistic you mentioned above, all I thought about is by having $0$ as I explained, how would I conduct my bootstrap sampling to reject or accept the null hypotheses? like what results am I looking for if I chose the statistic you suggested. I'm sorry I didn't quite get the three lines after it. Right now my knowledge is: Writing a Null hypotheses, Picking a statistic, bootstrapping while calculating the statistic each sample, conclusions.

Comment: Would using the difference work without the absolute value, and so I can check if zero is in my interval

Comment: Removing the absolute value would always give you $0$

Comment: Oof and here I go back to my starting point of choosing a statistic.. Sorry for bothering you alot, but do you have any idea on how to write my statistic in order to prove or disprove the Null hypotheses? I'm having trouble deciding what should I choose that would give me results that I can visualize and accept/reject my null hypotheses. (Sorry again for bothering, I can understand that my techniques or understanding is limited to what I saw in a couple examples of bootstrap and it might be hard to understand what I'm trying to find). Anyway I appreciate the help!